# MySQL DB connection with Orbeon Forms Tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, orbeon

looking for some support with MySql and Orbeon forms.  I've been at this for a few days, and I cannot seem to find any completed / published forms in MySql.  I've gone ahead and following the relational database instructions, created the DB / User, placed the mysql jbdc jar connector within tomcat\lib along with updating the server.xml and creating the properties-local.xml file within WEB-INF\resources\config.

I have set my tomcat port to 9700 on local host. DB schema is orbeon, user orbeon, password orbeon

My server.xml has the following additions.

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
<Context path="/orbeon" docBase="/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/webapps/orbeon" reloadable="false" override="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        poolPreparedStatements="true"
        username="orbeon"
        password="orbeon"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/>
</Context>

      </Host>

properties-local.xml has the following additions.

`<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
            
            <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*" value="/fr/service/mysql"/>
            <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>
            <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider" value="mysql"/>
            <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.jdbc-url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/>
            <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.username" value="orbeon"/>
            <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.password" value="orbeon"/>
            
</properties>`

I have not made any changes within tomcats context.xml or web.xml and wondering if these need to be updated as I could not find any recent threads regarding those settings.

My orbeon.log file shows,

2023-01-24T15:49:39,044 INFO  LoggerFactory - Configured Log4j 2 using property `oxf.log4j2-config` and configuration at URL `oxf:/config/log4j2.xml`.
2023-01-24T15:49:39,537 INFO  ProcessorService - Context listener - Context initialized.
2023-01-24T15:49:40,143 INFO  form-runner-auth - initializing
2023-01-24T15:49:40,144 INFO  form-runner-auth - configuring: FilterSettings(None)
2023-01-24T15:49:40,147 INFO  limiter - initializing
2023-01-24T15:49:40,148 INFO  limiter - configuring: FilterSettings(java.util.concurrent.Semaphore@ba3d5bb[Permits = 12],(/fr/.*)|(/xforms-server),(?!/([^/]+)/service/).+\.(gif|css|pdf|json|js|coffee|map|png|jpg|xsd|htc|ico|swf|html|htm|txt))
2023-01-24T15:50:23,517 INFO  ProcessorService - Servlet initialized.
2023-01-24T15:50:23,549 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: filter", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST"}
2023-01-24T15:50:23,549 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: chain", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST", "wait": "0"}
2023-01-24T15:50:23,576 INFO  auth - not setting credentials headers because credentials are not found
2023-01-24T15:50:23,590 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle"}
2023-01-24T15:50:23,590 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Received request
2023-01-24T15:50:24,280 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "ajax with update events", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,282 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "before document lock", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,289 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "got document lock", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79", "wait": "0"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,297 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "start: restore state", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79", "backOrReload": "false"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,373 WARN  CacheConfiguration - Statistics can no longer be enabled via configuration.
2023-01-24T15:50:24,588 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "end: restore state", "time": "292 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,595 INFO  XFormsServer - session not found while processing client events
2023-01-24T15:50:24,603 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Timing: 1013
2023-01-24T15:50:24,604 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "1,015 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,605 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: chain", "time": "1,056 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,605 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "1", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: filter", "time": "1,074 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,609 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: filter", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,609 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: chain", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST", "wait": "0"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,610 INFO  auth - not setting credentials headers because credentials are not found
2023-01-24T15:50:24,610 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,610 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Received request
2023-01-24T15:50:24,621 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "ajax with update events", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,621 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "before document lock", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,624 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "document lock busy (zero timeout)", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,625 INFO  XFormsServer - Ajax update lock timeout exceeded, returning error to client
2023-01-24T15:50:24,625 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Timing: 15
2023-01-24T15:50:24,627 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "16 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,627 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: chain", "time": "18 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:24,627 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "2", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: filter", "time": "18 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,642 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: filter", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,643 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: chain", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST", "wait": "0"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,651 INFO  auth - not setting credentials headers because credentials are not found
2023-01-24T15:50:29,652 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,652 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Received request
2023-01-24T15:50:29,672 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "ajax with update events", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,672 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "before document lock", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,672 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "document lock busy (zero timeout)", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,672 INFO  XFormsServer - Ajax update lock timeout exceeded, returning error to client
2023-01-24T15:50:29,673 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Timing: 21
2023-01-24T15:50:29,674 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "21 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,674 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: chain", "time": "31 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:29,674 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "3", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: filter", "time": "32 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,688 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: filter", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,688 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: chain", "path": "/xforms-server", "method": "POST", "wait": "0"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,714 INFO  auth - not setting credentials headers because credentials are not found
2023-01-24T15:50:39,715 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,715 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Received request
2023-01-24T15:50:39,734 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "ajax with update events", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,734 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "before document lock", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,734 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "xforms", "message": "document lock busy (zero timeout)", "uuid": "c25074f204c54f6a82757d47d2287f596159fd79"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,734 INFO  XFormsServer - Ajax update lock timeout exceeded, returning error to client
2023-01-24T15:50:39,735 INFO  ProcessorService - /xforms-server - Timing: 20
2023-01-24T15:50:39,736 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "20 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,736 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: chain", "time": "48 ms"}
2023-01-24T15:50:39,736 INFO  lifecycle - event: {"request": "4", "session": "5437F976D3D5DB6BF00C6B5745B629C1", "source": "limiter", "message": "end: filter", "time": "49 ms"}

`Please let me know if anyone has had this issue before.
Tomcat V 8.5
Orbeon Forms V2022.1 CE
MySql V8.0 community`
```

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in that part of the `orbeon.log` you have included here. Are you getting an error in the browser, for instance when saving a form from Form Builder? -Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the heads up.  Updating the properties-local.xml file with the single property line you provided did the trick. Backup and running with MySql

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the incorrect property name `oxf.fr.persistence.provider`, which is missing `.*.*.*` at the end of the name. So that property should instead read:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>
```

Also, you can remove all the other properties with `oxf.fr.persistence` in their name, as they are not necessary in this case. And for reference, this has also been discussed in [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/orbeon/c/rNGd092LLA8).